# SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType')

Tags: sql-server

I was recently going through all the options made available by Microsoft for the SERVERPROPERTY() in SQL Server.

When i write
SELECT 'License Type ', SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType')

I get output as

License Type  **DISABLED**

I went through the [knowledge base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) and it states the follows - 
" Unused. License information is not preserved or maintained by the SQL Server product. Always returns DISABLED. "

It would really be great if someone could suggest me a use of this Enum/Property as i find Microsoft Technologies too intelligent to keep things like these in the final released product if they are truly useless...

Any Ideas please...

Comment: It's probably left over from an early version and they have never got around to removing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This property used to contain information before 2008R2:

```
Mode of this instance of SQL Server.
PER_SEAT = Per Seat mode
PER_PROCESSOR = Per-processor mode
DISABLED = Licensing is disabled.
```

Licensing changed and it's now unused. The reason it is still there is probably that removing it might risk breaking something for someone (my guess).

Comment: Thanks for that and the previous different modes of licensing as well...

Comment: The `LicenseType` and `NumLicenses` server properties are useless since SQL Server 2005: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/295301/serverproperty-licensetype-returns-disabled-on-any-sql-server-2005-install